# Should I avoid crystallized honey when making mead?

Tags: mead, spoilage, honey-type

I've been making mead for while and have spotted some spots of crystallized honey occasionally. Today I started another one and realized that I got ~1kg of crystallized honey (16.66....% of total). I tasted it and have found no off flavor. Is there any risk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite an expert on beer making, but I have made honey ales a few times and was a beekeeper for about 8 years, so I have some honey knowledge. The crystallized honey is no different from normal honey. You can decrystallize it by suspending its container in warm water. This should make it a normal honey texture again, and it

Comment: I did put the bottles inside warm water,  I noticed they became more fluid, but nothing like the "usual" honey. Could this be related to honey quality?

Comment: It's possible. How long did you leave it in how warm of water? Also what kind of honey is it? If it's pure honey it should be fine either way; the stuff never goes bad.

Comment: 1 hour at 40~45 C. The label says its pure (wild honey literal translation). I believe it is, I found an small ant in one of the bottles haha.

Comment: Haha discard the ant, it's not needed for the mead. I think if you were to just get it as decrystallized as you can before using it, it will be easier o work with. I assume you'll be boiling it in the wort anyway, so that'll dissolve it. And for curiosity do you mind posting the recipe or a link to the one you were using?

Comment: Well, I never boil. The recipe is: 6kg of honey, 20l of water and 1.5l of Yeast starter (montrachet). OG 17.5 brix at 26 C. Will use SNA from [here](https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/how-to-brew/improve-mead-staggered-nutrient-additions/)

Comment: Alright. If you never bring the mixture to a boil I recommend trying to dissolve the crystals in water separately, then re-adding it. Perhaps separate the crystalline bits of honey from the others and dissolve them in a liter or two of the water then adding it in. The crystals are totally safe, but having the honey nicely dissolved will only make for a better brew.